# wordpress wp_signon function not working

Tags: wordpress

I am using wp_signon() function to login the user. I am doing this like

`$creds = array();`

`$creds['user_login'] = $username;`

`$creds['user_password'] = $password;`

`$creds['remember'] = true;`

`$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );`

i want to send user to home page after login.

But i Am facing following error:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at E:\xampp\htdocs\wpmoodle\wp-content\themes\twentyten\header.php:12) in E:\xampp\htdocs\wpmoodle\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 690.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`wp_signon()` needs to run before you've sent any of your actual page to the browser.

This is because part of what `wp_signon()` does is to set your authentication cookies. It does this by outputting a "Set-Cookie: ..." header -- if you look at line 690 of `pluggable.php`, where your error comes from, you'll see that that line sets a cookie.

So, because `wp_signon()` outputs *headers*, you can't already have sent any *content* -- because headers must always be output before content.

However, the error indicates that you've already sent some output -- on line 12 of `header.php`, presumably some of the first HTML of the standard WordPress theme.

This basically indicates that you need to move your `wp_signon()` call to somewhere earlier in the WordPress processing, so it has a chance to output its headers before any page content is sent.

Comment: Your answer has resolved my problem. I was not aware with this process that you gave me, It was knowledgable to me. Thanks you very much.-:)

Comment: Hi. I'm getting the same error. When should I run that function?  I'm executing `wp_signon` inside a plugin (which generate a shortcode). Thanks

Comment: Hi, facing the same issue here.  Any luck?

Answer (score 3):

If someone needs it, here is my solution:

```
function custom_login() {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $login_data = array();
        $login_data['user_login'] = sanitize_user($_POST['username']);
        $login_data['user_password'] = esc_attr($_POST['password']);

        $user = wp_signon( $login_data, false );

        if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
            echo $user->get_error_message();
        } else {    
            wp_clear_auth_cookie();
            do_action('wp_login', $user->ID);
            wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
            wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true);
            $redirect_to = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            wp_safe_redirect($redirect_to);
            exit;
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' );
```

Comment: I placed this code inside my function but getting "Too many redirects" error message because of this extra line I added these code..  $user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user($user_verify->data->ID);
    if (!empty($user_blogs)) {
        $siteInfo = array();
        foreach ($user_blogs as $site_id => $site_values) {
            $siteInfo[] = $site_values->siteurl;
        }
        wp_safe_redirect($siteInfo[0]);
        exit;
    }

Comment: The do_action part should be do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login, $user->ID);